# Whether SRIOV-networking supports SecurityGroup?

Tags: firewall, kvm, rhel7

How to configure firewall(SecurityGroup) in kvm Host when using sriov.

For example, I want to prevent arp spoofing in Host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the moment it is not supported.
There is a plan to support it with ovs hw offload